# Problem about graphs and probability theory

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

N students, all of different ages, went on a camping trip. With probability p, friendship is established between every two students, regardless of other likes or dislikes. When the trip ends in each pair of friends, the senior gives the younger a parting card. Find the mathematical expectation of those who have not received a single parting word.

Comment: This problem is a bit vague as is. Can a student potentially develop a friendship with *every* other student or just with a single one ? Since this is tagged as graph-theory I assume that one person can be friends with many other campers but it's not immediately clear

Comment: Friendship is made between any students with probability p

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, check [these guidelines](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask questions effectively. In particular, provide details about your own attempts to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Linearity of expectation is a powerful tool here.

Assume for the moment that the students are labeled $v_1,v_2,v_3,\dots,v_N$ in order of their age.

Take a look specifically at student $v_i$.

What is the probability that $v_i$ did not receive a parting card?  Well... that would have occurred in the instance that $v_i$ did not establish a friendship with any of $v_{i+1},v_{i+2},v_{i+3},\dots,v_N$.  What is the probability of that happening?

> $v_i$ not establishing a friendship with $v_{i+1}$ occurs with probability $1-p$.  Similarly so for establishing a friendship with $v_{i+2}$ and so on...  Multiplying these gives...

$~$

> Adding the respective probabilities that $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_N$ didn't get a parting card gives...